# AngularJS Material md-datepicker white screen background

Tags: angularjs, css, angularjs-material

I am trying to use a md-datepicker, and at the moment in which the datapicker is selected the rest of the screen goes blank seeing only the datepicker.
The code is the following:

```
<md-input-container flex="50">
      <label>Fecha nacimiento</label>
      <md-datepicker required ng-model="paciente.fecha" md-current-view="year" md-hide-icons="calendar""></md-datepicker>
</md-input-container>
```

And it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIO9Y.png).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, it was a problem with Angular Material CSS. I had version 1.1.0, updating to version 1.1.8 the error is solved.